# Showing that a set is neither closed nor open in metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have $F=\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and I have showed that F is not closed, now I also need to show that it is not open.

**My work:**

The definition of being open: $\forall x\in F \exists r>0: B_r(x)\subseteq F $

So what I need to show is: $\exists x\in F \forall r>0:B_r(x)\not\subseteq F$

Is this correct? And what x would work?

Comment: Strictly speaking, to answer this question it's necessary to know *what metric space* you're thinking of $F$ as a subset of, since that dictates what the elements of $B_r(x)$ will be. Is the big metric space $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, or something else?

Comment: Yes, you are correct I forgot to mention that. We are in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your negation of the definition of open is correct. Now, how would it apply to isolated points like $1$?

Consider $B_{0.5}(1)$. This is not a subset of $F$ since the ball contains the element $1.5$, which is outside of $F$. What about $B_{0.1}(1)$? What about $B_r(1)$ for any $r>0$?

Answer (score 0):

Take $\;\left\{\frac{n+1}n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset \overline F\;$ . Then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}n=1\in F$$

and thus $\;\overline F\;$ cannot be closed as it doesn't contain all its limits points, so $\;F\;$ can't be open

Comment: How do you conclude that F can't be open because $\;\overline F\;$ isnt closed. And wouldnt my method work?

Comment: @J.Doe What is your method? I can't see anything. And in a topological space (or metric space), a subset is open iff its complement is closed.